# Kafka 0.10 Replication Performance Decrease

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to benchmark Kafka Cluster. I am newbie. I build 3 node-cluster. Each node has one partition. I did not change default broker settings. I just copied producer and consumer code directly from official website.

When i create topic with replication 1 and partition 3, i was able to 170 MB per sec. throughput. When i create topic with replication 3 and parititon 3, i hardly see 30 MB per seconds throughput.

Then i applied production config in this link https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#prodconfig. The result got worse.

Can you share your experience with me?

```
disk type   replication insert count    one message length  elapsed time    req per sec concurreny  throughput MB
hdd 1   10,000,000  250 25  400,000 1   95.36743164
hdd 1   10,000,000  250 28  357,000 2   170.2308655
hdd 1   10,000,000  250 55  175,000 4   166.8930054
hdd 1   1,000,000   250 22  45,400  8   86.59362793
hdd 1   10,000,000  250 22  85,000  8   162.1246338


hdd 3   1,000,000   250 10  100,000 1   23.84185791
hdd 3   1,000,000   250 19  55,000  2   26.2260437
hdd 3   1,000,000   250 30  32,000  4   30.51757813
hdd 3   1,000,000   250 45  20,000  8   38.14697266
hdd 3   10,000,000  250 559 18,000  8   34.33227539
```

Answer (score 0):

You should expect performance to decrease when increasing replication. You're initial run had such high throughput because Kafka didn't need to copy the message data to multiple different partitions. When you increase the replication factor you're basically trading speed for durability.

Comment: I know all those concepts. I was expecting at least 70 MB/second.

Comment: What kind of hardware are you using?

Comment: Check the performance after increasing the partition count, I bet the throughput will shoot up. I missed that you only had it set to 1 before.